# How to pick a photo from windows phone 8 programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-8, photo

How to pick a photo from windows phone 8 programmatically and how to save that photo into mobile. Please Help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207050(v=vs.105).aspx

The above link: Capturing photos for Windows Phone

Answer (score 2):

There are built-in Launchers & Choosers experiences in WP7/WP8 that allow for easily capturing photos or retrieving photos from the phone's image library. Using the built-in photo choosers is the easiest way to get the default user experience.

You can read about CameraCaptureTask that allows capturing an image quickly on MSDN  @ [How to use the camera capture task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394006%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

You can read about PhotChooserTask that allows retrieving an image from the phone's photo library on MSDN @ [How to use the photo chooser task for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394019%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

If you want to build more complex image processing and camera capture apps you can read about the new WP8 APIs on Nokia's [Advanced photo capturing](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!advanced-photo-capturing.html) article.

Answer (score 2):

```
       // Try the following steps

       private readonly CameraCaptureTask _cameraCaptureTask; // Declare CameraCaptureTask

       if (null == _cameraCaptureTask) _cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
        _cameraCaptureTask.Completed += PhotoSelectionTaskCompleted;

      // In the completed event 

       void PhotoSelectionTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
       {
            if (null != e.ChosenPhoto && e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                var image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
                SaveImageToIsolatedStorage(image,"Image1.jpg");

            }
       }

      public void SaveImageToIsolatedStorage(BitmapImage image, string fileName)
      {
        using (var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (isolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
                isolatedStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);

            var fileStream = isolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName);
            if (image != null)
            {
                var wb = new WriteableBitmap(image);
                wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            }
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```